# Target specific object index/id out of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form set up that takes values and saves them into an object in a firebase array. I used ng-repeat to display each object in that array in a "dashboard" page. I want to be able to alter the specific object that gets created via checkboxes. I cannot figure out how to get the specific object.

```
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','firebase','ngMaterial']);

  app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
          .when('/second', {
              templateUrl: 'templates/second.html',
              controller: 'homeCTRL'
          })
          .when('/dashboard', {
              templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
              controller: 'homeCTRL'
          })
          .when('/vehicles', {
              templateUrl: 'templates/vehicles.html',
              controller: 'homeCTRL'
          })
          .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/dashboard'
          });
  }]);


  //controllers
  app.controller('homeCTRL', ['$scope', '$log','$firebaseArray', function($scope,$log,$firebaseArray) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://asgtodo.firebaseio.com");
      $scope.newItem = '';
      $scope.FBproject= $firebaseArray(ref.child('project'));
      $scope.FBhistory = $firebaseArray(ref.child('history'));

      $scope.projectName = '';
      $scope.dateStart = '';
      $scope.dateEnd = '';
      $scope.signChecked = '';
      $scope.paintChecked = '';
      $scope.blastChecked = '';
      $scope.labelChecked = '';
      $scope.yellowMacro = '';
      $scope.redMacro = '';
      $scope.otherPaint = '';
      $scope.pipeFootage = '';
      $scope.maxHeight = '';
      $scope.liftSmall = '';
      $scope.liftLarge = '';
      $scope.liftBoom = '';

      $scope.pipeCompleted = false;

      $scope.addItem = function() {

              $scope.FBproject.$add({
                projectName: $scope.projectName,
                dateStart: $scope.dateStart,
                dateEnd: $scope.dateEnd,
                signChecked: $scope.signChecked,
                paintChecked: $scope.paintChecked,
                blastChecked: $scope.blastChecked,
                labelChecked: $scope.labelChecked,
                yellowMacro: $scope.yellowMacro,
                redMacro: $scope.redMacro,
                otherPaint: $scope.otherPaint,
                pipeFootage: $scope.pipeFootage,
                maxHeight: $scope.maxHeight,
                liftSmall: $scope.liftSmall,
                liftLarge: $scope.liftLarge,
                liftBoom: $scope.liftBoom,
                pipeCompleted: $scope.pipeCompleted

              });
              $scope.projectName = '';
              $scope.dateStart = '';
              $scope.dateEnd = '';
              $scope.signChecked = '';
              $scope.paintChecked = '';
              $scope.blastChecked = '';
              $scope.labelChecked = '';
              $scope.yellowMacro = '';
              $scope.redMacro = '';
              $scope.otherPaint = '';
              $scope.pipeFootage = '';
              $scope.maxHeight = '';
              $scope.liftSmall = '';
              $scope.liftLarge = '';
              $scope.liftBoom = '';

      };

      $scope.changePipe = function(x){
        $scope.index = $scope.FBproject.indexOf(x);

      };

      $scope.rmList = function(item) {
        //get index of displayHold
        $scope.index = $scope.FBproject.indexOf(item);

        //add it to historylist
        $scope.FBhistory.$add($scope.FBproject[$scope.index]);

        $scope.FBproject.$remove($scope.FBproject[$scope.index]);

      };

      $scope.modalItem = function(item){

  return null;
      };



  }]);


  app.controller('secondCTRL', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  }]);
```

Here is the html

```
  <!-- MODAL BUTTON -->

  <div style="margin-top: 6em;">
      <div class="row animated shake">
          <div class="col s6 m5 l5">
              <center>
                  <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-dark blue modal-trigger" id="modal" href="#modal1">
                      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
                  </a>
              </center>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- MODAL -->

  <div id="modal1" class="modal bottom-sheet white" style="height: 100%; opacity: 0.8">
      <div class="modal-content white blue-text">
          <div class="row">
              <form>
                  <div class="row animated rollIn">
                      <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
                          <input id="projName" type="text" ng-model="projectName">
                          <label id="projNameLabel">Project Name</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
                          <label id="projDateLabel">Start Date</label>
                          <input id="projDate" type="date" class="datepicker " ng-model="dateStart">
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
                          <label id="projDateLabel">End Date</label>
                          <input id="projDate" type="date" class="datepicker" ng-model="dateEnd">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col s12 m2 l2">
                          <center>
                              <form action="#">
                                  <p class="padBoxes">
                                      <input type="checkbox" id="Signs" class="Materialize.showStaggeredList('#test')" ng-model="signChecked"/>
                                      <label for="Signs">Signs</label>
                                  </p>
                                  <p class="padBoxes">
                                      <input type="checkbox" id="Paint" ng-model="paintChecked"/>
                                      <label for="Paint">Paint</label>
                                  </p>
                                  <p ng-show="paintChecked" style="margin-left: 15px;" class="padBoxes">
                                      <input type="checkbox" id="Blast" ng-model="blastChecked"/>
                                      <label for="Blast">Blast</label>
                                  </p>
                                  <p class="padBoxes">
                                      <input type="checkbox" id="Labels" ng-model="labelChecked"/>
                                      <label for="Labels">Labels</label>
                                  </p>
                              </form>
                          </center>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col s12 m3 l3 z-depth-5" style="margin-right: 10px;" ng-show="paintChecked">

                          <center class="animated fadeIn">
                              <form action="#">
                                  <div class="indigo z-depth-2" style="height: 60px;margin-bottom: 30px;">
                                      <p>
                                          <h5 style="color: white; padding: 15px; float:left; font-weight: condensed">Paint</h5>
                                      </p>
                                  </div>

                                  <p class="range-field padBoxes">
                                      <label for="Labels">Yellow 646 Paint</label>
                                      <input type="range" id="test5" min="0" max="50" ng-model="yellowMacro"/>
                                  </p>
                                  <p class="range-field padBoxes">
                                      <label for="Labels">Red 646 Paint</label>
                                      <input type="range" id="test5" min="0" max="50" ng-model="redMacro"/>
                                  </p>
                                  <p class="input-field padBoxes">
                                      <input id="projName" type="text" ng-model="otherPaint">
                                      <label>Other</label>
                                  </p>
                              </form>
                          </center>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col s12 m2 l3 z-depth-3" style="margin-right: 10px;" ng-show="signChecked">

                          <form action="#">
                              <div class="col s12 animated fadeIn">
                                  <center>
                                      <div class="red z-depth-2" style="height: 60px;margin-bottom: 30px;">
                                          <p>
                                              <h5 style="color: white; padding: 15px; float:left; font-weight: condensed">Signs</h5>
                                          </p>
                                      </div>
                                      <p class="input-field">
                                          <input id="projName padBoxes" type="text" ng-model="pipeFootage">
                                          <label>Pipe Footage</label>
                                      </p>
                                      <p class="range-field padBoxes">
                                          <label for="Labels ">Max Height</label>
                                          <input type="range" id="test5" min="0" max="50" ng-model="maxHeight"/>
                                      </p>
                                  </center>
                              </div>
                          </form>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col s12 m2 l2 " style="margin-right: 10px;" ng-show="signChecked || labelChecked">

                          <center>
                              <p >
                                  <input type="checkbox" id="liftSmall" ng-model="liftSmall"/>
                                  <label for="liftSmall">Lift 3246</label>
                              </p>
                              <p >
                                  <input type="checkbox" id="liftLarge" ng-model="liftLarge"/>
                                  <label for="liftLarge">Lift 4069</label>
                              </p>
                              <p >
                                  <input type="checkbox" id="liftBoom" ng-model="liftBoom"/>
                                  <label for="liftBoom">Lift BOOM!</label>
                              </p>
                          </center>

                      </div>

                  </div>

              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12 m2 l2 padBoxes" style="margin: -50px;">
          <center>
              <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-dark btn-flat z-depth-2">
                  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 3em;">close</i>
              </a>
              <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-dark blue z-depth-2" onclick="Materialize.toast('Project Added', 4000)" ng-click="addItem()">
                  <i class="material-icons">add</i>
              </a>
          </center>
      </div>

  </div>

  <!-- FBproject -->

  <div class="container row" style="margin-top: 4em; ">
      <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
          <li ng-repeat="x in FBproject track by $index">
              <div class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-dark">
                  <div class="col s2 m2 l1">
                      <center>
                          <i class="material-icons">folder-open</i>
                      </center>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col s5 m2 l2">
                      {{x.projectName}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="col s12 m5 l4">
                      <center>
                          <div class="chip">Signs</div>
                          <div class="chip">Paint</div>
                          <div class="chip">Labels</div>
                      </center>
                  </div>

              </div>
              <div class="collapsible-body">
                  <div class="row">
                      <center>
                          <form action="#">
                              <p>
                                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="{{}}" />
                                  <label for="pipe">Pipe Ordered</label>
                              </p>
                              <p>
                                  <input type="checkbox" id="{{x.index}}"/>
                                  <label for="hotel">Hotel</label>
                              </p>
                              <p>
                                  <input type="checkbox" id="{{x.index}}"/>
                                  <label for="lifts">
                                      <h7>lifts</h7>
                                  </label>
                              </p>
                              <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-dark red" ng-click="rmList(x)">
                                  <i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
                              </a>
                          </form>
                      </center>
                  </div>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>

      <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.collapsible').collapsible({accordion: false});
              $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({dismissible: true, opacity: .50, in_duration: 300, out_duration: 200});
              $('.datepicker').pickadate({selectMonths: true, selectYears: 15, container: 'body'});
              $('select').material_select({container: 'body'});
              $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
          });
      </script>
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html ng-app="app">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
            <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
        </head>
        <body ng-cloak>
          <div>
              <div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal click-to-toggle" style="top: 5px; center: 24px;">
                  <a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-dark btn-large">
                      <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                  </a>
                  <ul>
                      <li>
                          <a href="#/dashboard" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-dark btn-large yellow darken-1">
                              <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>

                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="#/second" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-dark blue btn-large green darken-1">
                              <i class="material-icons">find_in_page</i>
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="#/vehicles" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-dark btn-large red darken-1">
                              <i class="material-icons">directions_car</i>
                          </a>
                      </li>

                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div ng-view></div>

        </body>

    </html>
```

section is question?

```
<div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="row">
                <center>
                    <form action="#">
                        <p>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.pipeCompleted{{index}}"/> <!-- what do I put here ?? to get the specific object-->
                            <label for="pipe">Pipe Ordered</label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
```

Comment: Im guessing that it has something to do with x in FBproject track by $index but i dont know how to use it :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="pipeCompleted[$index]"/>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Any messages in the console? "Didn't work" is very vague and without actual new code no one can tell if it wasn't a typo or naming mismatch. `pipeCompleted` vs `x.pipeCompleted` for instance.